# Retrofit Error: Service methods cannot return void message

Tags: java, android, eclipse, list, retrofit2

Happy new year to all,i'm working on an app that retrieves list of of objects from from an JSON  array and convert it to POJO class. However i recieve this error logcat with retrofit2 in android+Eclipse when i run the app as follows:

```
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/test(31013): Exception
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013): Process: com.nickSoft.unics_alpha, PID: 31013
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void.
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):     for method UnicsAgencyApi.getStreams
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createCallAdapter(ServiceMethod.java:228)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:160)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at $Proxy1.getStreams(Native Method)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.nickSoft.unics_alpha.Homepage.DownloadAgencyData(Homepage.java:582)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.nickSoft.unics_alpha.Homepage.ShowAllUnicsAgencyInfo(Homepage.java:548)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.nickSoft.unics_alpha.Homepage.onOptionsItemSelected(Homepage.java:394)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1016)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
12-31 06:59:32.405: E/AndroidRuntime(31013):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Api declaration code looks like this:

```
public static UnicsAgencyApi getUnicsAgencyApi() {

        if (sUnicsAgencyApi == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ENDPOINT_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            sUnicsAgencyApi = retrofit.create(UnicsAgencyApi.class);
        }
        return sUnicsAgencyApi;
    }

    public interface UnicsAgencyApi {

        @GET("api/uconnectservice/AllAgency")
        **void getStreams(Callback<List<AgencyModel>> callback);**
    }
```

Here is where i make the call:

```
RestApi.getUnicsAgencyApi().getStreams(new Callback<List<AgencyModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AgencyModel>> arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("Error in parsing", arg0.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AgencyModel>> AgencyModelData, Response<List<AgencyModel>> response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // ADD TO List here!!!!!!!!
                mstreamData.addAll(response.body());
                Log.e("Response", response.body().toString());
            }

        });
```

The origin of the error show in Logat is:

```
**void getStreams(Callback<List<AgencyModel>> callback);**
```

Please why am i getting this error or is there something i'm doing wrong ,please any guidance to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.
                                          cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using V1-like syntax with retrofit2.  There are no longer callbacks as parameters, you return a call instead. --

```
@GET("api/uconnectservice/AllAgency")
Call<List<AgencyModel>> getStreams();
```

You'll need to update how you call it, too. For asynchronous calls, use `enqueue` on the returned call --

```
RestApi.getUnicsAgencyApi().getStreams().enqueue(new Callback<List<AgencyModel>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AgencyModel>> arg0, Throwable arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.e("Error in parsing", arg0.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AgencyModel>> AgencyModelData, Response<List<AgencyModel>> response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // ADD TO List here!!!!!!!!
                mstreamData.addAll(response.body());
                Log.e("Response", response.body().toString());
            }

        });
```

Comment: i appreciated the response,hppy nw year 2017 :)